# Have sbt put javadocs and sources of dependencies on the class path

Tags: scala, resources, classpath, sbt

When using a managed dependency, I can tell sbt to download the javadocs and sources:

```
"mygroup" % "mymodule" % "myversion" withJavadoc() withSources()
```

But these jars don't seem to be on the runtime classpath?

What I would like to do, is access the javadocs and sources from my application. Can I make these jars appear as managed resources, such that I could do

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader.getResource("/my/package/MyDependency.scala")
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by adding a [classifier](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management#classifiers).

For a given library dependency, add a `javadoc` or `sources` `classifer`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.0.6" classifier "javadoc"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.0.6" classifier "sources"
```

Then, access its contents from the classpath:

```
val docStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("""/scalaz/Monad$.html""")
val doc = io.Source.fromInputStream(docStream).mkString
println(doc)
```

Here's a working example: https://earldouglas.com/ext/stackoverflow.com/questions/22160701/

Comment: Thanks James, that seems to work indeed. I had/have probably a problem with the sbt-idea plugin or the IntelliJ Scala plugin itself: If I create a run configuration inside IDEA, these resources are not found. But I just tested it with sbt-assembly, it _does_ include the sources and docs, so it is basically working correctly. Now I only have to find the best way to include the extra jars on the IDEA classpath.

Comment: Using `gen-idea no-classifiers` makes it work; it seems the two settings are otherwise conflicting.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of sbt has this, but my version has a built in method `withJavadoc()` that can be appended to any line. for example, `libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.0.6" withJavadoc()`. The same can be used for sources as well. Source: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html